# Qmail does not forward mail to a specific domain

Tags: email

I have a dedicated hosting account with GoDaddy.com. I've pointed my domain's email to work with Google apps.

The server has qmail running and it forwards email to all domains just fine except for MY domain (mydomain.com) - it says

```
 550 User xxx not found in mydomain.com
```

I believe it thinks I've hosted email on the server itself (not gmail) and it's trying to validate if xxx@mydomain.com exists on my server (which is not the case since it's all handled by google apps).

How do I make it forward mail to all domains?

Thank you :)

EDIT: I would only need it forwarding emails if the connection originates from 127.0.0.1 - which I believe is the default way it's configured. So to clarify: I just need a purely forwarded configuration so my PHP scripts have the ability to send email.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want an MTA at all...  Why not just bag the qmail server and point your PHP scripts directly to gmail for outgoing email?

Comment: problem with that is what happens when you can't connect to gmail (for whatever reason)? I prefer to have some sort of queue for sending mail very close close to the web scripts... whether that's a generic mqueue or a local smtp relay is up to the implementation, but i don't want my page bombing because of some random connectivity issue between me & google

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for the original poster, but maybe helpful if someone else comes around.

It sounds like mydomain.com is in /var/qmail/control/me and/or /var/qmail/control/locals.  Change me to something like "godaddy.mydomain.com" or some other hostname you control (maybe www.mydomain.com?) and use the same in locals.

You want to make sure that a bare "mydomain.com" doesn't appear in any of the files in /var/qmail/control, lest qmail think it's responsible for delivering the mail locally.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured all your MX records to point to Google?  I believe Google has 5 addresses you need to map for MX records.  Also, make sure you don't have any MX records pointing at GoDaddy's servers.

I'm not familiar with GoDaddy's hosting for qmail.  How much control do you have over qmail's configuration?  I you can edit the rcpthosts and locals, please provide the contents of those files.

Answer (score 0):

Sections 3.3 through 3.5 of the Life with Qmail would be very helpful:

http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#multiple-hostnames

[tomlogic](https://serverfault.com/users/4566/tomlogic) already mentioned similar ideas

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the one hand you are telling QMail that it handles the email locally and on the other you don't have the corresponding email accounts locally on your system

What you could do is use the [smtproutes](http://www.lifewithqmail.org/lwq.html#smtproutes) directive to tell QMail to redirect all emails for a particular domain to another host (in your case Google)

Edit the file (create it if it does not exist) `/var/qmail/control/smtproutes` and add a line

```
mydomain.com:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx can either be the IP Address of the server that is handling you email or you can substitute it with its FQDN. I have no idea what this is for Google Apps but it should be easy enough to find out.